# How to stop large 'angle jump' on a graph, as the angle moves above 360 and below 0 degrees?

Tags: excel, graph, angle, vba

I've got some heading data that I'd like to plot on a graph in Excel. My problem is that when the increasing angle reaches 360, it then drops down to 0. Similarly, when the decreasing angle reaches 0, it then jumps up to 360.

What I'd like it to do, is to continue increasing/decreasing so that my graph doesn't look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH5Y4.png).

For example, I'd like:

`331`
`344`
`358`
`2`
`7`
`13`
`5`
`355`
`349`

To be rewritten as:

`331`
`344`
`358`
`362`
`367`
`373`
`365`
`355`
`349`

I feel like there's an easy solution to this, but I just can't figure it out!

**EDIT:**

I'm plotting the data on a scatter graph, with angle plotted on y-axis, and time on the x-axis.

Comment: Please provide some more details, do you display data on excel chart - if so what type exactly?
What are the values of your other series? Any code behind the plot?

Comment: @Pav It's a scatter graph, with angle plotted on y-axis, and time on the x-axis. There's no code, just values for time and the angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to decide what works for you. Following formula might do the trick:

`=IF(AND(A2>350;B1<100);B1+360;IF(AND(A2<10;B1>260);B1-360;B1))`
I used data set in row 1 and initial value column A, cellA2 is the same value as A1 and B2 is the given formula, then drag the formula along your data set.
The way it works it checks if the previous value was >350 and if you current value is <100 then jump occurred so it adds 360, if not it checks if your previous value was <10 and current above 260 (which might not be needed as you don't seem to be getting values above 360) subtracts 360 from the current value.
Result look like this:
[image: Data set]

This solution is far from ideal as it does not take into account how many times you can reach the full angle, will your data be in range of to 0-720 or 0-3600? etc

Comment: Thanks! I thought something like that could work, but I could only get it to work for the first value that jumped between 0 and 360! The only trouble is, like you say, that it reaches the full angle multiple times (range of 0-1440) - how would you modify the formula to take this into account?

Comment: @jm00548  Yu can use modulo division (returns remainder) for the values that will be further multiplications of 360.
Alternative way would be the VBA code that loops through all cells and add n*360 to cells in range.

Comment: But to be honest, I understand you don't like the jumps on graph but for the phase plot of an angle it makes more sense to have that jump than actually going above 360.